# Hidden Directory Detected

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, directory, pci-dss

My company web application had a penetration testing done and there's a risk found is regarding the hidden directory:

- http://example.com/aux/
- http://example.com/cgi-bin/
- http://example.com/com1/
- http://example.com/com2/
- http://example.com/com3/

I don't think there's any folder of that name in the application.

So, the question is where did all those folder come from? and how to mitigate this issue?

extra info:
using Apache HTTP server on web server and Apache Tomcat on application server.

Comment: So then what HTTP response did the scanner get that makes it think there's something there?

Comment: it gets a "403 - Forbidden" response code

Answer (score 0):

They are probably re-written addresses. Check your `htaccess` files and your website configuration files for rewrite rules or virtual directories.